# Is /f/ more sonorous than other fricatives?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, sonority, berber

Tashelhiyt permits any segment to act as a syllable nucleus, regardless of sonority. There's lots of theoretical analyses out there, but descriptively, Tashelhiyt consonant syllabification moves left to right in a word, targeting the most sonorous segment first, assigning it an onset (if possible), and then syllabifying the next-most sonorous segment, unless it would create adjacent syllabic segments. Anything left over that can't be syllabified is a coda. The sonorant hierarchy for Tashelhiyt goes like:

> low vowel > high vowel > glide > liquid > nasal > voiced fricative
> voiceless fricative > voiced plosive > voiceless plosive

For example (from [Dell & Elmedlaoui 1985](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240271361_Syllabic_Consonants_and_Syllabification_in_Imdlawn_Tashlhiyt_Berber)):

> /rajrˤz/ [ra.jr̩ˤz] 'it will be broken'
>
> /ʜawltn/ [ʜa.wl̩.tn̩] 'make them(m.) plentiful'
>
> /tlbʒt/ [tl̩.bʒ̍t] 'you(sg.) stepped onto'
>
> /tzmt / [t̩.zm̩t] 'it(f.) is stifling'

If multiple eligible candidates are of the same sonority, the leftmost one generally wins:

> /rksx/ [r̩.ks̩x] (**r̩k.sx̩) 'I hid'

I found some examples in an acoustic study ([Ridouane 2008](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00382862/document)). Most of the syllabifications given perfectly match the description above, but some of the forms deviated concerning /f/; when syllabification has the chance to target /f/ or a another fricative, it will apparently always choose /f/, *even if* the other fricative is the leftmost candidate, *even though* both are voiceless fricatives and apparently of the same sonority:

> /tkʃf/ = [tk̩.ʃf̩] (not [t̩.kʃ̩f]) 'it dried'
>
> /sfqqst/ = [sf̩q.qs̩t] (not [s̩f.qːs̩t]) 'irritate him'

I want to know if this phenomenon arises because /f/ is more sonorous than /s/, or if there's some other explanation. Perhaps when presented with otherwise equally eligible candidates, Tashelhiyt will first choose the leftmost one, unless it would create a word-initial onsetless syllable, in which case it will choose to syllabify the rightmost one. That seems to be partly true--that's probably why /tkʃf/ is [tk̩.ʃf̩] instead of [t̩k.ʃf̩]. But this doesn't explain another example given, /sxf/ [s̩.xf̩] 'fade away'; if the syllabification where instead [sx̩f], that would avoid an onsetless syllable. Instead, [s̩.xf̩] seems to show /f/ being syllabified before /x/, suggesting that there is also a sonority hierarchy where /f/ is more sonorous than /x/ as well as /s/.

This seems counterintuitive to me--I'd think sibilants would be *more* sonorous than /f/, not less. Any insight into this phenomenon would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 5):

Insofar as sonority is the phonologization of perceptual prominence and robustness, *f* would be one of the least-sonorous fricatives, ahead of [θ,ɸ] but behind [s,ʃ,x,χ,ħ], which either have higher-amplitude fricative noise or more-perceptible noise concentrated in optimal frequencies. [The spectrum of [f]](https://www.mq.edu.au/about/about-the-university/faculties-and-departments/medicine-and-health-sciences/departments-and-centres/department-of-linguistics/our-research/phonetics-and-phonology/speech/acoustics/speech-acoustics/fricatives) is fairly flat

Comment: I suspected as much! I'm stumped to explain the Tashelhiyt data then.